# How do I run a command on login and have it appear in the console?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, zsh, tmux

For example have it run tmux attach -d right when I login. .bashrc, .profile and the like seem to run it in the background? I want to see the action run in the terminal right after I login. I tried adding command="echo 1" entry to authorized_keys in .ssh that runs the command and logs me out which was not what I wanted.

Comment: did you try <yourcommand> 1>/dev/tty and put it in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run something run right away as part of `.bashrc` when starting a login shell, put these as the last lines:

```
if shopt -q login_shell; then
    exec tmux attach -d
    # run exit if you want to be logged out if the exec fails, otherwise omit
    exit
fi
```

However, this will mean you won't be dumped into an actual `bash` shell, and when `tmux` exits, you'll be logged out.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work for me because that executes every time a new shell is open. So if I open another shell in tmux it opens another tmux. tmux in tmux is hard to work with

Comment: I updated the answer to check for a [login shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26782), so subsequent non-login shells won't run the command.

Comment: ended up using this
    if [[ -o login ]]; then
        tmux attach -d
    fi